# this context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In the following code, the "this" keyword references the "myName" object. Why doesn't the "this" in console.log reference the "window" object, since it is really "window.console.log"?

```
class Name {
  constructor(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
  superGreet() {
    console.log('I am', this.firstName);
  }
}
 
let myName = new Name("Jay");
myName.superGreet();
```

Comment: Arguments to a function are evaluated in the caller's scope, not the scope of the function being called.

Comment: "*since it is really `window.console.log()`?*" - that doesn't matter. The `this` keyword inside the `log` method call is the `window.console` object, not `window`. (But as Barmar said, this has no relevance to the `this` evaluation in the arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments are evaluated in the caller's scope, not the scope of the function being called. So

```
  superGreet() {
    console.log('I am', this.firstName);
  }
```

is equivalent to

```
  superGreet() {
    let temp = this.firstName;
    console.log('I am', temp);
  }
```

In this rewrite you can see that `this` is in the scope of `myName.superGreet()`, not `window.console.log()`. So `this` is the value of `myName`.

Answer (score 1):

When `console.log('I am', this.firstName);` is run, the arguments are evaluated first before calling `console.log`. Therefore `this.firstName` is evaluated in the context of the Name object, and the `this` refers to the Name object.